# Did I fry my Furnace Control Board? (C -> G rewire attempt)

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

So while I was attempting to figure out how to get our fan to run independent of our heating/cooling, I looked at our thermostat wiring and discovered that it only had wires running to C, W, Y, and RC/RH.  I'd read that it was common in older homes for the "G" fan relay wire to get used as the Common wire, so I tried swapping the wire from C to G to see if it would work (and popping in batteries onto the thermostat, knowing that it was no longer getting power from the C line).

But it turns out I missed the critical part where you have to re-wire the control HVAC side as well.  So effectively, I likely ended up wiring the "Common" line to the "Fan Relay" line on my thermostat.  I switched the wire back to the original position on the thermostat, but it looks like I may have already done damage, as the thermostat now no longer powers up without batteries, and with batteries, I'm unable to start up the cooling or the heating system.

Is it possible that I fried the control board on the furnace, just by attempting this wire switch?

Additional context: It looks like the thermostat is functioning properly, in that I can hear it "clicking" on to attempt to turn on the heating or the cooling system... but it just doesn't seem to trigger anything on the HVAC side.

Comment: Have you moved all the wires back to where they were before and done a full power-cycle of the HVAC system?

Comment: Flipping the breaker should be a full reset, so if that + moving the wire back didn't solve the problem then it is possible something got fried.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I've put the wire back in its original place, and we've tried flipping the breaker as well as toggling the switch on the JBox next to the furnace unit.  Not sure if flipping the breaker labeled "air conditioning" sufficiently resets all the associated/connected units for the HVAC system though,

Comment: Have you always had the problem with the fan or is it something new?

Comment: For as long as I can remember, we haven't been able to operate the fan independently from the heating/cooling system.  So I did some research today and tried to figure out why, and it was clear from the wiring that we didn't have a wire hooked up for the independent fan relay control on the thermostat.
So, given the common practice of re-wiring the fan relay wire to common wire, I thought I could just switch it back (at the cost of needing batteries for the thermostat).  Unfortunately this didn't work and seems to have left us worse off than before. :(

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: The diagram is in this spec: https://www.hvac.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/carrier_58CTA_specification.pdf

Answer (score 3):

#### How thermostat signaling works (and how to test manually)

First, a little background about the thermostat control: It's dumb. Really dumb. The signaling is done by simply shorting wires together. The R wire is shorted to W to call for heat, or R shorted to Y to call for cooling, or R shorted to G to call for fan. Stuff, like digital thermostats, can be powered between the R and C wires.

You can test the furnace controls without the thermostat. Simply short the R and W (or R and Y) wires together and verify that heating (or cooling) begins.

This can be tested right at the furnace control board too, avoiding all doubt about the thermostat wiring. Note that the control board is often found in the blower cabinet and you're going to have to defeat a safety switch to perform testing there. It's your responsibility to ensure this is done safely -- you don't want clothing, long hair, or other things being sucked into the blower while working here. There also may be high voltage terminals exposed, so be careful about what you touch. Bypass the safety switch with one hand and, with one or two other hands, touch a jumper wire (a paperclip will do) between the R/W or R/Y terminals on the control.

#### What probably went wrong

To call for fan the thermostat will short R to G. But you had C on the G terminal, so the thermostat shorted R to C. That's a dead short across the 24v transformer in the furnace. Either the switch in the thermostat will have failed, or something in the furnace will have failed. Control boards often have a small fuse, about 2 amps or so, to protect the 24v side of things. It could be that the fuse has been blown.

#### How to diagnose further

If the manual tests shorting R/W and R/Y didn't cause the furnace to operate then get a multimeter and set it for AC volts. Turn on all power to the furnace and safely bypass the blower door safety switch if appropriate. Confirm (measure) that full AC mains voltage is supplied to the controller. If it is, then measure voltage between R and C terminals. You should find something in the neighborhood of 24-32 volts. If not... we'll have to dig deeper by examining the control board for a fuse, testing continuity of the fuse, testing the output voltage of the transformer upstream of the fuse, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!  It is most likely as I feared - I did the one wire move that probably really screwed things up on the furnace end.  By the way, this likely means that to achieve my goal, the thing I *could* have done was re-wire the heat line to the fan line for now - it would have removed my ability to start the heater temporarily until I moved it back, but at least I would have gained access/control over the fan line.

Comment: @Calvin Go ahead and do some troubleshooting to determine which part is broken. If it's the control board, and if you're already handy with electronics or if the price of a replacement board motivates you to become handy with electronics, we can help figure out if it's as simple as a blown fuse and how to get that repaired.

Comment: @GregHill  Great answer!  I think your approach is great.  Most boards won't get fried by a missconnected tstat...as you said, tstats are basically switches.  They may have some intelligence as to WHEN they make the connections, but at the end of the day, they are switches.   I suspect a blown fuse someplace as you suggested.  Again, great answer. +

Comment: I agree good answer testing at the control board best bet probably popped a fuse some times pico fuses are used they look like a resistor but are fuses. + there is a fuse on the incoming hot to the control board 120v.